# copy and swap technique uses copy constructor inside assignment operator function

Tags: c++

I was reading "Effective C++ by Scott Meyers", in which Item 11 is recommending is to use the "copy and swap" technique inside my assignment operator:

```
Widget& Widget::operator=(const Widget &rhs)
{
    Widget temp(rhs); // Copy constructor
    swap(temp); //Swap with *this
    return *this;
}
```

But in Item 12 it is written:

> It makes no sense to have copy assignment operator call the copy constructor.

I think that Item 11 and Item 12 are contradictory. Am I understanding it incorrectly?

Comment: You're probably reading that out of context.

Comment: This code should use pass-by-value, allowing the compiler to generate a copy or move.

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes `pass-by-value` is another technique but this one is also correct.

Comment: @EmptyData, you don't understand what Ben meant.

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes I understand that in case of `pass-by-value` makes a copy to argument and then swap that argument with `this`

Comment: @EmptyData Ben's point is that the copy can be replaced by a move if the context is right, which is not the case with your function as-is.

Comment: The posted implementation is correct for pre-c++11, which Effective C++ is about. Read Effective Modern C++ later. And the sentence in Item 12 actually means: *"It makes no sense to have copy assignment operator call the copy constructor on `*this`."*.

Comment: @LogicStuff Got it! Thanks

Comment: @LogicStuff I'm pretty sure the copy can be elided in C++03 when passing by value.

Comment: @juanchopanza Sorry, my bad. The pass-by-value version is also explained in the book.

Comment: Beware the copy swap technique.  It is the right solution about 2% of the time.  It can be very expensive for very common situations.  http://www.slideshare.net/ripplelabs/howard-hinnant-accu2014 slides 43-53.

Answer (score 3):

In the 2 citations of "Effective C++ by Scott Meyers" that you mention the 2 different aspects are discussed.

- In the code fragment in Item 11 Scott shows one of the ways to implement the assignment operator.
- In Item 12 the citation you mention deals with avoiding code duplication between the assignment operator and copy constructor. One paragraph above your citation says:

> the two copying functions will often have similar bodies, and this may tempt you to try to avoid code duplication by having one function call the other.

My understanding of this part of Item 12 is like this: if you try to write something like below (to have copy assignment operator call the copy constructor) then it will be wrong:

```
PriorityCustomer::PriorityCustomer(const PriorityCustomer& rhs)
: Customer(rhs),   // invoke base class copy ctor
  priority(rhs.priority)
{
  logCall("PriorityCustomer copy constructor");
}

PriorityCustomer&
PriorityCustomer::operator=(const PriorityCustomer& rhs)
{
  logCall("PriorityCustomer copy assignment operator");
  this->PriorityCustomer(rhs); // This line is wrong!!!
  return *this;
}
```

Answer (score -7):

I do the opposite.  I overload the assignment operator to do a "deep" copy (meaning you consider dynamic memory and instantiate new copies accordingly).  Then use the assignment operator in copy constructor.  Can't comment on your text because I don't have that book.

```
Widget::Widget(const Widget& existing) : dynamicThingie(0)
{
    *this = existing;
}


Widget& Widget::operator=(const Widget& existing)
{
    a = existing.a;
    b = existing.b;

    delete dynamicThingie;
    dynamicThingie = new Thingie();
    memcpy(dynamicThingie, existing.dynamicThingie, lengthOfDynamicThingue);

    return *this;
}
```

Comment: It is not exception-safe, and it forces default initialization of members in copy ctor.

Comment: OP code creates an entire throw-away local object, I don't see how that's better.  It might even be less efficient.  OP code doesn't appear to be any more exception-safe either.

Comment: Fundamentally, a copy assignment operator needs to (1) clean up existing resources, then (2) copy the contents of the argument. A copy constructor needs to just do step (2), and doing step (1) would actually be a really bad thing because there's nothing to clean up. For this reason, it's much safer to have the assignment operator use the copy constructor, not the other way around. The copy-and-swap technique does make a new object, but doing so is actually quite cheap - it's initialized using the copy (or move) constructor, which does the copy, and the new object dtor does all the cleanup.

Comment: Aappearances can be deceiving. Read the book to find out where your inplementation got it wrong.

Comment: @Kyle Sweet OP's code (actually, Meyers' one) is exception-safe, because `swap` is nothrow. Now, see what happens with your object, if `b = existing.b` or `Thingie()` throws...

Comment: templatetypedef: point taken because "delete dynamicThingie" would be bad if dynamicThingie were non-initialized and non-zero.  StoryTeller: my implementation didn't "get it wrong", it just doesn't use the copy and swap method.  All: Saying "the copy and swap method is exception-safe so long as you write the code carefully so it doesn't throw exceptions" seems like a waste of words.

Comment: Igor: If Thingie() can throw here it can throw in the swap subroutine.  Why is it better over there than over here?

Comment: People are so mean on this site!  Just trying to understand why code isn't expected to throw exceptions when it's moved to a function called "swap" but it is expected to throw exceptions when it's a function called "operator="

Comment: @Kyle, non-throwing swap does not allocate anything, typically it just swaps pointers - of course, if 'Widget' is designed in the way that allows such swapping.

Comment: If swap doesn't do any necessary allocating, then the copy c'tor must do it.  Same problem.

Comment: @IgorR. It isn't `nothrow`, it is exception safe in the sense that it has roll-back semantics in case of exceptions. An exception can arise when performing a copy.

Comment: @juanchopanza `operator=` is exception safe ("strong guarantee"), `swap` is nothrow.

Comment: @Kyle Sweet copy ctor may throw, it's ok. We were talking about `operator=` which wasn't exception-safe.

Comment: Why is it better to have a function that doesn't throw when you still must use a function that does throw? I still don't see the benefit or why that overall code is any safer from exceptions.